# Are there any open source C Library (not c++) for Windows Driver Development?

Tags: c, open-source, device-driver, kernel

Are there any open source C Library (not c++) for Windows Driver Development ?

I am developing a network device driver that need some functionality such as RegEx, string manipulation, Object Oriented by C and XML and so on...

thanks.

Comment: You want to use Regex and string manipulation in a driver???

Comment: Why not? More work than in user-mode, but there's nothing that would prevent this from being possible. Though not very effective, yes ...

Comment: I want to check packet contents by RegEx and save my data by XML in Kernel mode !
I can write these LIBs but before I want to be sure there is not any other solution.

Comment: snort might be a good source of routines for packet checking.

Comment: Xml saving inside a driver is asking for trouble! Please reconsider...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not aware of any real regular expression libraries. However, depending on what you need [FsRtlIsNameInExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546850(VS.85).aspx) may be of some interest. There's plenty of string manipulation functions in the [Safe String Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff563644(VS.85).aspx), they just have names that are different to the libc equiavalents.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't do this in a driver. It would be frowned upon in the Windows driver communities.

What keeps you from communicating with a UM module of your product to do such more error-prone operations? Keep the operations, especially risky ones, to a minimum within a driver. When your UM module crashes, it may take down a process, when your driver crashes it will inevitably take down the system.

No question: it's possible. But not everything that is possible should also be done ;)