# FsRtlIsNameInExpression never matches anything

Tags: c, string-matching, windows-kernel

I do string matching in a kernel driver using the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://srcvault.scali.eu.org/cgi-bin/Syntax/Syntax.cgi?BoyerMoore.c), but I also need to implement basic wildcard support. [This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627677/591064) mentionned the function [`FsRtlIsNameInExpression`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which looks just right for my needs. It even looks like it handles case insensitivity for Unicode strings.

But it can't even get it to match a simple string with itself.

I tried a few things, but FsRtlIsNameInExpression never matches anything. Here is some code I used to test (I put the call to `MyTest` at the end of my `DriverEntry` routine).

```
NTSTATUS MyTest()
{
    int matches = 0;

    UNICODE_STRING a3times;
    UNICODE_STRING A5times;
    UNICODE_STRING bbb;
    UNICODE_STRING patterna;
    UNICODE_STRING patternb;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&a3times, L"aaa");
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&A5times, L"AAAAA");
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&bbb, L"bbb");

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&patterna, L"a*a");
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&patternb, L"b*");

    if(FsRtlIsNameInExpression(&patterna, &a3times, TRUE, 0)) 
        ++matches;            // a*a should match aaa

    if(FsRtlIsNameInExpression(&patterna, &A5times, FALSE, 0))
        ++matches;            // a*a should match (insensitive) AAAAA

    if(FsRtlIsNameInExpression(&a3times, &a3times, TRUE, 0))
        ++matches;            //aaa should match aaa

    if(FsRtlIsNameInExpression(&patternb, &bbb, TRUE, 0))
        ++matches;            //b* should match bbb

    return matches;   //Should be 4, but is 0
}
```

For the record :

- I am using WDK version 7600.16385.1, checked build (my code, not Windows)
- The driver runs in a Virtual Box hosted Windows 7 Pro 64 bits on my Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits
- The driver is signed by a test certificate
- I trace the code in a kernel debugger
- The code does not crash, but can't be called in user mode

What is the obvious that I am missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says

> If `IgnoreCase` is `TRUE`, `Expression` must be uppercase.

Note that, per your comments, you misunderstood the case-sensitivity parameter. It is `IgnoreCase` not `CaseSensitive`.

As for the results:

1. Lower-case expression with `IgnoreCase` set to `TRUE` - won't work
2. Lower-case expression, `IgnoreCase` set to `FALSE`, *upper case* pattern - won't match
3. Lower-case expression with `IgnoreCase` set to `TRUE` - won't work
4. Lower-case expression with `IgnoreCase` set to `TRUE` - won't work

Just really bad luck that not a single one worked :)

Comment: Another proof that Murphy lurks late at night ! It works, I was able to match `J'ai déjà testé ça et j'ai détesté ça` with `*TE?TÉ*`.

Comment: Glad to be of help! J'adore le code, et il vous aimera en retour. Déteste le code, et il vous déteste le dos.